# How do I define multiple routes in OpenVPN?

Tags: networking, openvpn, haproxy

I'm trying to set up a server to act as a gateway - basically it will deal with connections coming from a k8s cluster to the external world (mainly databases behind VPNs).

So I have the following setup: OpenVPN with specific routes, and HAProxy that act as gateway.

In my .opvn config file, I have something like this:

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-256-CBC
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM
auth SHA1
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote A_REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS 1199 udp4
verify-x509-name "vpn.mycompany.com" name
auth-user-pass
pkcs12 myp12file.p12
tls-auth mytls-tls.key 1
remote-cert-tls server

route-nopull
route DATABASE_A_IP_ADDRESS 255.255.255.0
route DATABASE_B_IP_ADDRESS 255.255.255.0
route 192.0.0.0 255.255.255.0

verb 4
ping 5

log-append /var/log/openvpn/sellbievpn.log
status /var/log/openvpn/sellbievpn-status.log
```

The HAProxy config is something like this:

```
frontend entry
    bind :1433
    mode tcp
    use_backend sqlserver

backend sqlserver
    mode tcp
    server sqlserver DATABASE_A_IP_ADDRESS check
```

Now if I try to connect to `myserver:1433` I can succesfully connect to DatabaseA. So that's perfect, the concept works. But I can't find a way to connect to DatabaseB, even though they share the same VPN Network. So I'm guessing the problem should be on how I configured to `routes`.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `push "route [subnet] [netmask]"` in your server configuration.

Comment: Hm, I though the "push" method was for testing only. Isn't it what I've done when I did `route DATABASE_IP 255.255.255.0`? I don't understand why IP_A works and IP_B doesn't

Comment: If the config file you showed is only on client side, it is definitely not the right way to ask one client to route to another via the vpn server without settings on it. Typically `client-to-client` would help connections of Client A - vpn server - Client B, but you need to use the virtual IP generated in vpn for connection. If you want to use original IP, you need to first turn on ipv4_forward and then corresponding add routing policies to that vpn server machine.